# How to store value in NSMutableArray from ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, nsmutablearray

I'm tying to solve my problem which is, i don't know how to store value from (for ex) 4 viewControllers and keep it in the last one. It should be like the scorecard, in  first quarter I earned 4pt (and write it in TextField), in second quarter 5pt etc. In the last one it should be summed and sorted etc.
i stared from the last ViewController called it Result, another four called first, second etc. 
In Result i created

`@property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *array;`

first, second etc inherits array from result and for First I created:

```
-(void) prepereForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender :(id)sender
{

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"id1"]) {

    NSString *str1 = [_firstResult text];

    Result *Result1 = [segue destinationViewController];

    Result1.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [Result1.array addObject:str1];

}


}
```

for second:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"id2"]) {
     NSString *str2 = [_SecondResult text];

     Result *Result1 = [segue destinationViewController];

    Result1.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [Result1.array addObject:str2];
     }
}
```

When I run the project in array is just the last score from fourth quarter.
I think that i shouldn't alloc and init NSMutableArray in each viewController but i don't know how make it work..
Please Help me. 
Appreciate!

Comment: Create NSMutableArray in AppDelegate or create separate class which manage your scorecard and use it with sharedInstance in all controllers

Comment: *Result1 should be *result1 ;). (Basic naming convention)

Comment: You're right Clement sorry for that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, you are, every time creating a new array which have its current and single object.
Create a shared object and call that array to save and fetch values.
Or just create a array in appdelegate.

Comment: Ok. So when I create array in appDelegate how can i init and alloc this? And Each controllers must inherits from appDelegate right? Sorry for question like this but everyone was a beginner once.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you are creating a new array that's why array contains only last value. create an array in appDelegate or use shared object to save the results.